# Why doesn't my quicksort algorithm work for repeated elements?

Tags: c, sorting, quicksort

I have implemented a quicksort algorithm in C to sort the elements of an array. It works for all cases except when an the array has two or more equal elements. I've been trying to fix it and have been debugging it but I can't seem to manage to get it to work when there are repeated elements.

I'd appreciate any assistance on how I can change my code to work for repeated elements too.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Random Array Length
#define L 10
#define MAX 100

void smarter_sort(int[],int,int);
void swap(int[],int,int);
int choose_piv(int[],int,int);

int main(){

    int i, a[L];

    //Generate an array of random numbers
    for(i=0; i<L; i++)
        a[i]= rand() % (MAX+1);

    //Unsorted Array
    printf("\nUnsorted array: ");
    for(i=0; i<L; i++)
            printf("%d    ", a[i]);

    //Sorted Array
    smarter_sort(a,0,L-1);
    printf("\nSorted array:   ");
            for(i=0; i<L; i++)
                printf("%d    ", a[i]);
    return 0;
}

//Recursively defined quicksort (Pseudo-code listing 1.9)
void smarter_sort(int a[], int l, int r){
    if(r > l){
        int piv = choose_piv(a, l, r);
        smarter_sort(a, l, piv-1);
        smarter_sort(a, piv+1, r);
    }
}

//Swap Elements
void swap(int a[], int i, int j){
    int t=a[i];
    a[i]=a[j];
    a[j]=t;
}

//Choosing the pivot (pseudo-code listing 1.10)
int choose_piv(int a[], int l, int r){
    //defining pointers and pivot
    int pL = l, pR = r;
    int piv = l;

    while (pL < pR){
        //finding the first left element greater than piv
        while(a[pL] < a[piv])
            pL++;

        //finding the first right element greater than piv
        while(a[pR] > a[piv])
            pR--;

        //swapping if the pointers do not overlap
        if(pL < pR)
            swap(a, pL, pR);

        if(a[pL]==a[piv]||a[pR]==a[piv]){
            pL++;
            pR--;
        }
    }
    //swapping and returning the rightmost pointer as the pivot
    swap(a, piv, pR);
    return pR;
}
```

Comment: Debuggers are your friend. Just like your friends in real life, you must exert some effort in order to keep the relationship valuable.

Comment: @mah,  nah.

Just kidding, I can see where it goes wrong but I don't know what I can do to fix it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your code modified in order to work properly even with array containing equal elements:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 //Random Array Length
 #define L 10
 #define MAX 100

 void smarter_sort(int[],int,int);
 void swap(int[],int,int);


 int main(){

    int i, a[L];

    //Generate an array of random numbers
    for(i=0; i<L; i++)
       a[i]= rand() % (MAX+1);

    //Unsorted Array
    printf("\nUnsorted array: ");
    for(i=0; i<L; i++)
        printf("%d    ", a[i]);

    //Sorted Array
    smarter_sort(a,0,L-1);
    printf("\nSorted array:   ");
        for(i=0; i<L; i++)
            printf("%d    ", a[i]);
    return 0;
 }

 //Recursively defined quicksort (Pseudo-code listing 1.9)
 void smarter_sort(int arr[], int left, int right) {
      int i = left, j = right;
      int pivot = arr[(left + right) / 2];


      while (i <= j) {
           while (arr[i] <pivot)
                i++;
           while (arr[j]>pivot)
                j--;
           if (i <= j) {
                swap(arr,i,j);
                i++;
                j--;
           }
     };


    if (left < j)
          smarter_sort(arr, left, j);
    if (i < right)
          smarter_sort(arr, i, right);
 }


//Swap Elements
void swap(int a[], int i, int j){
    int t=a[i];
    a[i]=a[j];
    a[j]=t;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `if (arr[i] <= arr[j])`?